# How to separate HCl and NaOH from an aqueous solution of NaCl?

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment

At home I make experiments on salt (as it is easily available at home). 
One day I came to know that on mixing salt and water I will get Hydrochloric Acid and Sodium Hydroxide. So I became really excited, but my excitement broke into small pieces because I don't know how to separate $\ce{HCl}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$ from the solution of $\ce{NaCl}$ and water.

Comment: I don't think you can. And if you can then certainly not at home.

Answer (score 5):

The solution can be electrolyzed to produce chlorine and sodium hydroxide solution.  The chlorine can be added to water to produce HCl and HOCl.

Comment: Also, the chlorine can be burnt with the hydrogen appearing at the cathode.

Answer (score 2):

> One day I came to know that on mixing salt and water I will get Hydrochloric Acid and Sodium Hydroxide [...]

No, you won't!

In theory, electrolysis of a sodium chloride solution and photolysis of the combined gases formed (hydrogen, chlorine) will provide you with hydrogen chloride, as I have outlined [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/8948/how-to-separate-hcl-and-naoh-from-salt-and-water-solution/8950#8950).  In reality, you might want to avoid this - unless you're planning to jump out of the genetic pool ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reaction you are speaking of if NaCl + H2O -> HCl + NaOH, witch is the oppisate of a neutralization reaction of sodium hydroxide and hydrochloric acid and generly goes in the oppisate direction you are speaking of. in theory you could find a way to produce the reverse reaction but it would be hard and not cost efferent, the best way to produce hydrochloric acid and sodium hydroxide is by electrolysis of molten salt which will give chlorine and sodium.